# How to theoretically fit and test for t-distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, t-distribution, method-of-moments

I'm trying to test some data for the best distribution fit, and am looking to try the t-dist (all theoretically, no R computations)
I think the best way to do this is to assume the distribution is true, use MLE or MoM to estimate parameters and then conduct a goodness-of-fit test.
Firstly, is this an appropriate way to do it?
Secondly, what is the theoretical derivation for the parameters of the t-dist (using MLE or Mom)
And thirdly, how do you estimate the degrees of freedom for a t-test?

Thanks

Comment: If you are fitting a t distribution the number of degrees of freedom is a parameter being estimated; it is not given independently.

Comment: Take a look: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63647/estimating-parameters-of-students-t-distribution