# How Can We Measure Error In Bits of Information?

Tags: error, curve-fitting, measurement

Curve fitting, using conventional measures of error, such as [LSE (Least Squares Estimation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), cannot include the complexity of the formula because the complexity of the formula must be measured in bits and is therefore incommensurable.  However, if one can measure the total error in units of bits, it can be added to the complexity of the formula in bits to approximate the [Kolmogorov Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of the data which, in turn, provides approximate [Solomonoff Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomonoff%27s_theory_of_inductive_inference).

There must be some measure of error in units of bits.  What is it?

Comment: LSE can be interpreted as using a cross entropy loss and a normal distribution assumption, so it is already is already in bits.

Comment: So the sum of formula complexity and squared error of its predictions could be a model selection criterion.  Is there a name for such a selection criterion so I can look up the literature on it?

Comment: If you haven't already, you should probably look at Rissanen's work on stochastic complexity.

Comment: Yes, models selection using AIC as below in my answer below. Also, BIC.

Answer (score 4):

Your bits imply [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)), a type of [self-information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory), is applied in the context of [Kullback-Leibler Information](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~shu3/Presentation/AIC.pdf) to generate [AIC](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~shu3/Presentation/AIC.pdf) (Akaike Information Criterion) values under the assumption of maximum likelihood conditions. Those AIC values are then used for [regression model selection](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02294361.pdf) under [certain conditions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/234662/99274).

Comment: +1 One of the most efficient, simple, and well annotated answers I've seen on this site.

Comment: @EdM I'm blushing. Took me a while to understand AIC, I guess the work paid off.